# Large Ripple on Synchronous Boost Converter

Tags: mosfet, ripple

I was working on the synchronous boost converter simulation with the following schematic, with SUP70101EL (P-channel MOSFET) and IRFB4310Z (N-channel MOSFET). I don't understand why the output voltage has such a large ripple. I tried to increase the output capacitance and increase/decrease the ESR of the capacitor, but doesn't seem to get any better.

I tried to add delay for the gate signal on the PMOS to simulate the dead-time but still no luck. I really don't know what I did wrong on this schematic.

Please help me

[image: Synchronous Boost Converter Schematic]
[image: N-Channel MOSFET VDS, VGS]
[image: P-Channel MOSFET VDS, VGS]
[image: Inductor Current (IL1)]
[image: Boost Converter Output Voltage]
[image: VGS, NMOS, and PMOS]

Comment: Welcome! Show Vgs and Vds for both U1 and U2 and IL3.

Comment: @winny I already updated the graph you mentions, I hope you can help me fix it. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Plot the Vgs of U1 and U2 in the same plot and zoom in on the transition. Ask yourself if 700 A is a realistic current. If not, what could cause it?

Comment: @winny Sorry, I really don't know why

Comment: Then plot the Vgs as I asked you and compare with a working boost converter.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146280/discussion-between-user17443911-and-winny).